# How to report this ICE for gcc-trunk

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, bug-reporting

I would like to get this code work

```
#include <cstddef>

template <bool B, auto T, auto F>
struct conditional { static constexpr auto value = T; };

template <auto T, auto F>
struct conditional<false, T, F> { static constexpr auto value = F; };

template <std::size_t N, auto... Dims>
struct static_extent;

template <std::size_t N>
struct static_extent<N> {
   static constexpr std::size_t value = 0;
};

template <std::size_t N, auto Dim, auto... Dims>
struct static_extent<N, Dim, Dims...> {
  static constexpr auto value =
     conditional<
        (N == 0),
        Dim,
        static_extent<N-1, Dims...>::value
     >::value;
};

enum class dynamic_extent_tag {};
inline constexpr dynamic_extent_tag dyn{-1};

int main()
{
    static_assert(static_extent<1, 33, dyn, 19>::value == dyn, "");
    static_assert(static_extent<0, 33, dyn, 19>::value == 33, "");
}
```

I have tested it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/iFvTKs) and it seems to work with clang. I am unfortunately bound to gcc which gives me an ICE plus a stack trace. I tried to surf on their [bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) and i am kinda lost.

Is it even worth to put up an bug report for the trunk version? Is it even wanted?
Does someone knows if it is already a known problem?
I looked for the keyword "ice" but I could not find anything useful there.

Comment: *"Is it even worth to put up an bug report for the trunk version? Is it even wanted?"* I would say so, yes - maybe more so than any other version!

Comment: it appears that you can only search bugzilla if you are logged on, and that new accounts are currently not allowed due to spam. So you are out of luck unless someone files this bug for you.

Comment: Well I think it might be in bugzilla now. I checked today and i believe there was a submission today which mighy touch my problem as well. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all ICEs should be reported.

I've opened https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79556 for you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I've written an email to get an account and access to bug reports. No Answer yet... I have more ICE's, which i could deliver. I do alot of development with Concepts and I see errors from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer for all readers, that find your question:

- Yes, it is highly appreciated to file bug reports for trunk. During the development stage, it is far more easy to fix bugs compared to after a release.
- Yes, it is wanted. If the bug or regression was introduced a couple of days or weeks ago, the change is still present and less difficult to fix.

How should you proceed?

- Try with the lastet version of trunk or as new as possible.
- Recompile your code with added `-save-temps`. This will produce a .i (for C, it will be .ii for C++) file.
- Compile with same flags as above but with the .i/.ii file to check that the problem remains.
- Post bug at gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/, include the error message, GCC version (`gcc - v`), and attach your .i/-ii file.

By the way, LLVM/Clang work in a similar way: https://releases.llvm.org/1.9/docs/HowToSubmitABug.html

Further reading:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/
- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Gcc-ICE-reporting-guide